# Rust not compiling to executable in Linux

Tags: linux, rust, rust-cargo

Compiling rust on Linux with `rustc` or `cargo build` produces a shared library instead of an executable file.
My file manager (thunar) and `file` command show that file type as shared library.

And the compiled binary can only be executed via terminal by `$ /path/to/file` or `$ cargo run`.
That file cannot be executed just by double clicking as other executables can be.
Output from `file` command:

`$ file rust_bin`

> rust_bin: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86_64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=cb8cd... , with debug_info, not stripped`

Comment: Please show what exact commands you are running and what exact messages they produce.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Your compiler produces an executable file. There is no big difference between a shared library and a dynamically linked executable file. They follow the same basic format. The string `interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0` indicates that this is an executable and not a library. Libraries don't normally have an interpreter set. Try running `file` on some files you know are executables, and some other files you know are libraries, and see for yourself. An interpreter is usually a small system program that loads and executes a shared object. A file can actually serve as both a library and an executable at the same time (the most common example is your `libc.so.6` or whatever it is called on your system; try running it).
2. If you can run this executable from your shell but not from your file manager, the problem is with the file manager, not with the executable. You may have to specifically instruct the file manager that your program should run in a terminal. This usually can be done by creating a .desktop file that describes your program. In addition, desktop tools may mis-recognise modern executables as shared libraries. [This](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/shared-mime-info/issues/11) is a common problem. It too can be remedied by creating a .desktop file for your executable. It is not specific to rust in any way.

Bottom line, there's nothing wrong with `rustc` or `cargo` or the way you are running them.

Comment: It is executable, it can be executed in terminal `./file` but not from file manager(thunar xfce4), seems like file manager is not recognizing shared libraries and not executing them as other executables can be executed just from the file manager and produce same output from `file` commamd.  I found something related on launchpad.net [Shared libraries not being executed by file mamagers](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shared-mime-info/+bug/1639531)

Comment: @Amiy "seems like file manager is not recognizing shared libraries". No, this is not what happens here. The file is an executable and not a shared library. The bug reports talks about a bug/misconfiguration in the GUI. It thinks the file is a shared library, when it isn't. Nothing to do with rustc really.

Comment: @Amiy Apparently this is a common bug. On my machine I cannot run *any* executable from a file manager. I never use a file manager so I wouldn't have discovered it on my own.

Comment: `RUSTFLAGS="-C relocation-model=dynamic-no-pic link-args=-no-pie" cargo build `produces an executable.And `gcc -no-pie src.c` for gcc .I generally use vim or nano but I just tried today to execute it from file manager and it didn't.As I was thinking that if I give the binary to someone else they won't be able to execute it without opening terminal.This happens also with programmes compiled with GCC whether I use `-no-pie` option or not.So The problem is with GUI file managers.

Comment: @Amiy if you give your program to someone and you expect them to use GUI, you should also give them a .desktop file and an icon anyway.

Answer (score 1):

When you create your project initially you can simply use cargo new (or init) to get the right type

```
cargo new my_project_name
# OR create a lib project
cargo new --lib my_library_name
```

when you use rustc you can use a command-line option

```
rustc lib.rs
# lib.rs has to contain a main function
# OR to build a lib
rustc --crate-type=lib lib.rs
```

Your finding about shared object is misleading your error hunt: https://askubuntu.com/questions/690631/executables-vs-shared-objects - it's not a problem, an executable can be a shared object.

I think in your case the problem is another. What does you binary do? Does basically just print something via stdout and that's it? Maybe this is the reason why double clicking in the gui file browser does not show you anything, it runs a millisecond and is over before you know it.

Have you tried waiting for input at the end of the main function? Just so that the user can read the output and hit Return key.

```
use std::io;
fn main() {
    // do and print stuff

    // Wait for return key
    let mut input = String::new();
    match io::stdin().read_line(&mut input);
}
```

Not sure how thunar will deal with it but eventually he will open a terminal and show the result and close the terminal when enter is pressed.

Answer (score -1):

```
cargo build
```

creates an executable file in target/debug/rust_bin
Then just

```
./target/debug/hello_cargo # or .\target\debug\hello_cargo.exe on Windows
```

to execute, or just

```
cargo run
```

PS: you need to create a Cargo.toml file with the appropriate data inside.